# Issues getting a Docker container to connect to 2 different physical NICS

Tags: docker

We have a server connected to an internal VLAN and an outward facing connection on two separate physical NICs.  I need one container to access both to be able to aggregate the data from both sources.  Unfortunately searching for connecting a docker container to multiple networks gets a flooded list of responses about connecting containers to multiple internal docker networks.  How do I get the container to recognize both host networks so it may request some data from one and from the other?

Comment: You shouldn’t have to do anything special, assuming your host’s route table is correct.  What specific problems are you running into?

Comment: It is only ever seeing and communicating on the one NIC.  It hasn't been pushed to production but locally on OSX it won't see both the wireless card and the nic, or two nics.  However if I run the microservice locally it accesses both just fine.  It only shows one nic when running docker network inspect nic

Comment: shortened for char limit.  

`docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "0b78fa1c40a649c6272c8542eff51f2adbdf13065e70708082c9f9c67f7011a0",
        "Created": "2019-05-07T20:28:46.695463094Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
      `